# Why is the exponential function used in Cox regression?

Tags: survival, cox-model, proportional-hazards

I am trying to get my head around Cox regression. I found quite a good paper on the subject by R. Tibshirani: [A plain man's guide to the proportional hazards model](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ftp/plain.pdf).

On page 66 he states:

> For mathematical convenience, $r(x)$ is usually chosen to be $exp(k\ times\ x)$.

What is this "mathematical convenience", why don't we determine $k$ directly?

(one idea that I have is that when calculating the risk ratio it is constant over the entire range when using the exponential function... which seems to be a connection to the Poisson distribution where you use it because of the same effect.)

Comment: The hazard has to be positive so an easy way to insure this is to restrict $r(x)$ to be positive which is achieved by  $exp()$ function.

Comment: @JesperHybel: Thank you... do you think that this is the only reason? Would you bother to form an answer out of your comment?